# Define row of CSV file if row contains specific string

Tags: python, csv

I've been studying Python for two weeks and there's something I want to know when reading and writing CSV file in Python.

I used `def` codes for output:

```
def csv(filename):
  f = open(filename, 'rU') 
  lines = []
  for line in f:
    lines.append(line.rstrip('\n').split(','))
f.close()
return lines
```

And the result from above codes looks like:

> [['a', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['b', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['c', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['d', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['e', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['f', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['g', '', '', '', '', '']]

Let's say I want to change the value of first row that contains `'a'`.

What codes can I use to define the row containing `a`?

Comment: This is not a csv file. Looks like python output

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry. you are right. This is python output of my csv file.

Comment: Looks like you answered you own question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024944/replacing-values-in-csv-by-using-python), right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, use [built-in csv parser](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).

This code will define a python list of rows which contains 'a':

```
import csv
rows = csv.reader(open('yourfile.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
arows = [row for row in rows if 'a' in row]
```