# Replacing values in csv by using python

Tags: python, csv

```
def update(all_marks, stud_num, mark, column, result):
    lines = [l for l in all_marks]

    for row in all_marks:
        if stud_num in row:
            lines[rows][column] = mark
```

From here, I am trying to replace the value by using `lines[rows][column] = mark`.

It is supposed to replace the existing value with mark.
But there's a problem with defining rows.
Anyone knows how to fix?
Thanks.

Edit:
Here's sample of data from all_marks:

> [['a', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['b', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['c', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['d', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['e', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['f', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['g', '', '', '', '', '']]

What I want to do here is to replace the value in '' with mark.

For example, def update(all_marks, 'a', '10', 2, True): will return

> [['a', '', '10', '', '', ''],
>
> ['b', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['c', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['d', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['e', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['f', '', '', '', '', ''],
>
> ['g', '', '', '', '', '']]

Thanks for helping a newbie.

Comment: Please take care to format your code properly. The one that you posted won't even run. Also what exact problem do you encounter?

Comment: would you be able to post a sample of data from all_marks?

Comment: Did you try the Python [csv modul](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)? It works fine for tasks like yours.

Comment: @Dreen: Thanks for a comment. I've uploaded a sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your function that will return the output as expected:

```
def update(all_marks, stud_num, mark, column):
    for i in range(len(all_marks)):
        if stud_num in all_marks[i]:
            all_marks[i][column] = mark
    return all_marks
```

And here is how it works:

```
>>> marks
[['a', '', '', '', '', ''], ['b', '', '', '', '', ''], ['c', '', '', '', '', ''], ['d', '', '', '', '', ''], ['e', '', '', '', '', ''], ['f', '', '', '', '', ''], ['g', '', '', '', '', '']]

>>> update(marks,'a','10',2)
[['a', '', '10', '', '', ''], ['b', '', '', '', '', ''], ['c', '', '', '', '', ''], ['d', '', '', '', '', ''], ['e', '', '', '', '', ''], ['f', '', '', '', '', ''], ['g', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

Note that `marks` is now modified

```
>>> marks
[['a', '', '10', '', '', ''], ['b', '', '', '', '', ''], ['c', '', '', '', '', ''], ['d', '', '', '', '', ''], ['e', '', '', '', '', ''], ['f', '', '', '', '', ''], ['g', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

If you want to change that so that update simply returns a copy of modified data change the function in the following way:

```
def update(all_marks, stud_num, mark, column):
    tmp = all_marks
    for i in range(len(tmp)):
        if stud_num in tmp[i]:
            tmp[i][column] = mark
    return tmp
```

Comment: I initially posted the code and just updated my answer to give you some more information

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code:

```
def update(all_marks, stud_num, mark, column, result):
    lines = [l for l in all_marks]
    for row in range(len(all_marks)):
        if all_marks[row][0] == stud_num:
            lines[row][column] = mark
```

And here are the explanations:

```
for row in range(len(all_marks)):
```

=> you don't want to iterate over list objects (e.g. ['a','','','','','']) but over *list indices*

```
if stud_num == all_marks[row][0]:
```

=> This is to check only the first character of your row, not *any* character.

```
lines[row][column] = mark
```

=> typo here, should be *row* and not *rows*

Comment: Dreen beat me up for a few seconds on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Looping on the row indices isn't as efficient as looping on the rows themselves. A more pythonic way would be

```
def update2(all_marks,stud_num,mark,column):
    for row in all_marks:
        if stud_num in row:
            row[column] = mark
    return all_marks
```