# python csv | If row = x, print column containing x

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am new to python programming, pardon me if I make any mistakes. I am writing a python script to read a csv file and print out the required cell of the column if it contains the information in the row.

```
   | A  | B | C
---|----|---|---
1  | Re | Mg| 23 
---|----|---|---
2  | Ra | Fe| 90
```

For example, I `if-else` the row C for value between 20 to 24. Then if the condition passes, it will return Cell A1 (Re) as the result.

At the moment, i only have the following and i have no idea how to proceed from here on.

```
f = open( 'imageResults.csv', 'rU' )
for line in f:
     cells = line.split( "," )
     if(cells[2] >= 20 and cells[2] <= 24):
f.close()
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024553/define-row-of-csv-file-if-row-contains-specific-string) might contain the answer to my question but i can't seem to make it work.

---

**UPDATE**

If in the row, there is a header, how do i get it to work? I wanted to change the condition to string but it don't work if I want to search for a range of values.

```
   | A  | B | C
---|----|---|---
1  |Name|Lat|Ref
---|----|---|---
2  | Re | Mg| 23 
---|----|---|---
3  | Ra | Fe| 90
```

Comment: `if int(cells[2]) >= 20 and int(cells[2]) <= 24:` in line 4 of your code. Otherwise you're comparing a string to an integer, which can cause a lot of problems.

Comment: Furthermore it is better to use a csv parser, since the csv format is more complicated than one thinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a csv reader. It's built into python so there's no dependencies to install. Then you need to tell python that the third column is an integer. Something like this will do it:

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        if 20 <= int(line[2]) <= 24:
            print(line)
```

With this data in `data.csv`:

```
Re,Mg,23
Ra,Fe,90
Ha,Ns,50
Ku,Rt,20
```

the output will be:

```
$ python script.py
['Re', 'Mg', '23']
['Ku', 'Rt', '20']
```

*Update*:

> If in the [first] row, there is a header, how do i get it to work?

There's `csv.DictReader` which is for that. Indeed it is safer to work with DictReader, especially when the order of the columns might change or you insert a column before the third column. Given this data in `data.csv`

```
Name,Lat,Ref
Re,Mg,23
Ra,Fe,90
Ha,Ns,50
Ku,Rt,20
```

Then is this the python script:

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for line in csv.DictReader(f):
        if 20 <= int(line['Ref']) <= 24:
            print(line)
```

P.S. Welcome at python. It's a good language for learning to program

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and it solved my issue! I have another question, if lets say I am gonna put a header (string) in the row with numbers, how do I get it to work? For example (Top to down), Ref>23>90 >50 >20

Comment: @xainnnn: I've added a section for dealing with the header in above's answer